# Without using cordova plugin post message on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cordova

Using this link [facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin](http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/) I create an phonegap Facebook app. In that app application when I am login that application it working fine. It give me facebook friendlist, birthday, friend links and its allow to me to post on Facebook wall me and my friends Facebook wall. but when I logout and logging into another user then it allow me to login but its gives me that message **The User hasn’t authorized the application to perform this action.** And when I try to post some thing then it gives me that error **This does not let testing post to Facebook your public profile is you name, profile and other public info**

I am using

1. latest cordova build
2. In developer.facebook my application name is Testing
3. I am using API v1.0

following code is to share the post

```
    function share() {
    openFB.api({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/me/feed',
        params: {
            message: 'Testing Facebook APIs',
        },
        success: function() {
            alert('the item was posted on Facebook');
        },
        error: errorHandler});
}
```

Please remember its working fine for me but when I logging using another user then it gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this while logging out the first user :

Revoke permissions :

```
openFB.revokePermissions(
     function() {
     },
     errorHandler );
```

Comment: Is there any mistake I will do in Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

If it's working for you only then check if your app is in developer mode or not.

1. Go to your app facebook dashboard.
2. App review tab.
3. Check and turn on to make your app public.

Hope it helps with your question.